Cannot see full commit message in git commit log
When I look at the git commit log in VS Code under SOURCE CONTROL, it only shows the first line (aka subject) of each commit. As I tend to write detailed commit messages, it feels awkward that I cannot see that information anymore.
Of course, I can use gitk or just git log to get everything, but did I just not find that functionality or is it simply not there? Looking through context menus, preferences and search engines could not yet help me.

This question is similar to: How can I view the Git history in Visual Studio Code?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@jonrsharpe I'm not convinced that it's a duplicate.

@jonrsharpe No, it's not duplicate because the problem is not to show the history as in the other item but to show the "full commit message" as pointed out in the title already.

In the "Source Control" view, if you expand the "COMMITS" tab instead of the "SOURCE CONTROL" one, you can see more details for commits. There, if you hover over the commit, it'll show you the full commit message.


I think, in my VS Code version, that section which shows the commit history is called "SOURCE CONTROL GRAPH" and the hover popups show the subject line only as well. But right, that's where I would have expected it to be shown even though for lengthy messages that need scrolling, this wouldn't be sufficient.

@TilmanVogel Even long messages show up well for me with plenty of space to display them. I'm using version 1.92.2 on Linux but other platforms should have the same setup.
